# Inner_join and filter, disappearing observations

Tags: r, filtering

I am working on a project related to the Agenda 2030 and I downloaded some files from here https://unstats.un.org/sdgs/indicators/database/

I got the same problem with all of them, so let's take as example the goal n.12.
Once I downloaded and uploaded the xlsx in R, I want to filter it according to the "Indicator" embedded in the data. But first, I combine it with another dataframe, downloaded from here (https://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=gdp&d=SNAAMA&f=grID%3a101%3bcurrID%3aUSD%3bpcFlag%3a1).

```
df <- read_excel("Goal12.xlsx")

gdp <- read.csv("UNdataGDP.txt", header = TRUE, sep="|")

gdp<- rename(gdp, GDP = Value)
gdp<- rename(gdp, Country = Country.or.Area)

joinedf <- inner_join(gdp, df, by = c("Country" ="GeoAreaName" , "Year"="TimePeriod"))

joinedffilter <- filter(joinedf, Indicator == "12.1.1")
```

The problem regards the last command. When I specify certain indicators, it gives me back dataframes with 0 rows.

If I use

```
unique(df[c("Indicator")])
# A tibble: 11 x 1
   Indicator
   <chr>    
 1 12.1.1   
 2 12.2.1   
 3 12.2.2   
 4 12.3.1   
 5 12.4.1   
 6 12.4.2   
 7 12.5.1   
 8 12.6.1   
 9 12.a.1   
10 12.b.1   
11 12.c.1
```

I do know that there is the indicator 12.1.1 in the original dataframe, but some of them get lost when I use inner_join to combine the dataframes. Indeed, if I use

```
unique(joinedf[c("Indicator")])
     Indicator
1       12.a.1
2       12.c.1
9       12.2.2
161     12.4.1
880     12.b.1
940     12.4.2
2023    12.5.1
6669    12.3.1
```

As mentioned, the indicator 12.1.1 is disappeared.

Hoping that I gave you all the needed information, and that it will not take much time to understand the problem here, may you please explain where are the mistakes? I am new in using R Studio and I am trying to improve.

I anticipately thank you very much! Such a great community.

Comment: So why do you expect `inner_join` to return all results? see [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)

Comment: If you want to keep all the `Indicator` variables try using `full_join`.